# "at the time" and "at that time" usage and differences

Tags: expressions, the-that

Are the expressions "at the time" and "at that time" interchangeable?

What are the differences between the two? How do use them?

Comment: @Satwik is right. Also, 'At that time' refers to a specific point in time whereas 'At the time' refers in general a period in time.

Comment: [“At the time” versus “at that time”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41959/at-the-time-versus-at-that-time)

Answer (score 2):

The phrase **"at that time"** establishes a reference to the context of this phrase (e.g "The great War was fought in the beginning of the 20th century. *At that time*,....") , relating it  to the time, of the event being discussed in the context preceding this phrase. But the phrase **"at the time"** is usually followed by an explicit time reference, usually by using the simple preposition "of" (e.g "*At the time* of the Great War...") which separates the time reference from the preceding context and adds it after the phrase. It is seldom used without the preposition "*of*" and usually refers to a comparatively less specific instant of time, than **"that time"**.

Comment: [This dictionary](http://dictionary.sensagent.com/at%20the%20time/en-en/) says that the expressions are equivalent:
at the time (adv.) / at that time, in those days, then >> I agree with this, with the proviso that there needs to be a contextual temporal indicator with either variant. '"at the time" is **often** _followed_ by an explicit time reference, **often** using the simple preposition "of" '. Not always: He had given a quick glance up and down the street and then had slipped inside and bought the book.... At the time he was not conscious of wanting it for any particular purpose. [1984]